# Grid view binding

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I am binding an Object datasource to a grid view. My object has a collection of items in one of the properties.Which is a List. How do I Loop thru this and bind the items to a column in GridView?.

Comment: If I am correct then each row maps to one of your Objects, but you want one of the columns to be bound to a property on that object which is a collection. My big question is how exactly do you intend to display this collection? Asp.Net doesn't know how to render a collection when binding a column. If you let us know how you want it to display then we might be able to help you.

Comment: I've revised my answer to provide a [not very elegant] work-around to your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit:** updated to call a method in the code behind to generate html markup for the collection.

In your aspx markup you could have something like the following:

```
    <asp:GridView ID="myGridView" AutoGenerateColumns="False" runat="server">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Item Name" DataField="Name" />
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Collection Field">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <%# ((_Default)Page).GetHtmlForList(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "List"))%>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

then in your code behind you could have something like this:

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            myGridView.DataSource = GetCollection();
            myGridView.DataBind();
        }
    }

    public string GetHtmlForList(object value)
    {
        string html = "";
        List<string> list = (List<string>)value;
        foreach (string item in list)
            html += item + "<br/>";
        return html;
    }

    private List<MyClass> GetCollection()
    {
        List<MyClass> coll = new List<MyClass>();
        coll.Add(new MyClass { Name = "First Item", List = new List<string>(new string[] { "1", "2", "3" }) });
        coll.Add(new MyClass { Name = "Second Item", List = new List<string>(new string[] { "Apples", "Pears", "Oranges" }) });
        coll.Add(new MyClass { Name = "Third Item", List = new List<string>(new string[] { "Red", "Green", "Blue" }) });

        return coll;
    }
}

public class MyClass
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<string> List { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: One of the property of my object is a List<SomeObject>. How do I bind the SomeObject in a Column?.

Answer (score 1):

Get the Collection from the object and bind it by using

```
myGridView.DataSource = myCollection; 
myGridView.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you not have a Repeater inside the Col. template, and simply bind your List to it in the RowDataBound?